# Dashboard in odoo10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10, dashboard

I am new in Odoo.

Is it possible to create new dashboard in odoo10? I want to create dashboard for my pettycash module. If is it possible, How? I appreciate the links and advices.

Answer (score 0):

All Depends in what kind of dashboard do you need. I suggest you to look at how are developed the currents dashboards that ships with Odoo. You could see several like Website, Sales, Invoicing, etc.

You will need to be familiar to Odoo internals and how to code in Odoo to be able to bring complex features alive but also you could add several actions views to compose a custom reporting dashboard by installing the module `board`

Comment: I am exploring now and try to look in the code of hr_dashboard but it's very confusing for me as a newbie in QWeb, JS